# How hide image path in django?

Tags: python, html, django

Is it possible to hide the path to the image so that it is not visible in the element expect? I dont want to allow user know where is my images are a storing. How i can hide this in django?
[image]

```
<div class="avatar avatar--large active">
  <img src="{{user.avatar.url}}"/>
</div>
```

Can you give an example with my code?

Answer (score 0):

To remove html from your DOM

```
 $("#a").remove();
```

if you want to hide only then use

```
$("#a").hide();
```

Comment: Can you give an example with my code, please? I'm not very familiar with html and js